# Binding parameters with MySQLi throws "undefined method" error?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have this code:

```
$dateInt = intval($date);
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM establecimientos WHERE timestamp > ?');
$stmt->bindParam($dateInt);
$stmt->execute();
```

And I'm receiving this error:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam()

I'm sure there's something terribly wrong, but I cannot certainly know!

Comment: On a side note, I believe this version of bindParam is used in a pdo connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes. The `bind_param` method requires a datatype hint as the first parameter and it is `bind_param` and not `bindParam`

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $dateInt);
```

Check the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Thank you! And the lesson is: less copy-paste, more Documentation!

Comment: Yup: copy/paste has caused more compilation errors than anything, _Been there, oh yes_

Answer (score 4):

It is `bind_param()`, not `bindParam()`. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).